# Delete Incremental Rows in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, row, increment, delete-row

I have a full year of of 24 hour, hourly data with 3 unnecessary rows between each day (set of 24 hour rows). I would like to delete all of these unnecessary rows. My current method is to increment 24 spaces up, delete 3 rows, and then loop back to the 24 space increment until the value of the last row (lRow) is <1 in which case the loop will stop. Please see below for my current code:

```
Sub Delete_Rows()

    Dim lRow
    lRow = 9468

    Do While lRow >= 1
        lRow = lRow - 24
        Sheets("Sheet 1").Rows(lRow).Delete
        lRow = lRow - 1
        Sheets("Sheet 1").Rows(lRow).Delete
        lRow = lRow - 1
        Sheets("Sheet 1").Rows(lRow).Delete
    Loop

End Sub
```

However, I keep on getting a Run Time Error: 1004 on this line:

```
Sheets("Sheet 1").Rows(lRow).Delete
```

I can't figure out why that is and any help or alternative methods to accomplishing this goal are appreciated.

Comment: `lRow >= 1` only gets checked *once for each pass through the loop*, so within the loop you can still decrement `lRow` to be < 1.

Answer (score 0):

Tim is absolutely right. Now, I think deleting rows one by one is costly in terms of speed, so might as well try below.

```
Dim c As Range, rngtodelete As Range
For Each c in Sheets("SheetName").Range("A1:A9468") 'change this to suit
    If c.Value <> "" Then
        If rngtodelete Is Nothing Then Set rngtodelete = c _
        Else Set rngtodelete = Union(rngtodelete, c)
    End If
Next
If not rngtodelete Is Nothing Then rngtodelete.EntireRow.Delete xlUp
```

Comment: Thank you @L42, I'm getting an error with this script saying "Invalid Outside Procedure". Here is what I currently have:

Comment: Dim c As Range, rngtodelete As Range
For Each c In Sheets("LoadProfile").Range("A1:A9468") 'change this to suit
    If c.Value <> "" Then
        If rngtodelete Is Nothing Then Set rngtodelete = c _
        Else: Set rngtodelete = Union(rngtodelete, c)
   ' End If
'Next'If Not rngtodelete Is Nothing Then rngtodelete.EntireRow.Delete xlUp

Answer (score 0):

If the rows are truly blank then you can do this in a single shot with `SpecialCells`. Assuming that column A contains the blank data:

```
Sub Cull()
' in case there are no blank cells
On Error Resume Next
Range("A1:A9468").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
End Sub
```

You haven't specified your Excel version, but given you data layout you won't be running into the [SpecialCells 8192 Limit](http://www.excelguru.ca/blog/2009/07/23/excel-2010-finally-fixes-specialcells-8192-limit/) that occurs in xl07 and earlier.

Comment: Hello @brettdj
My apologies, I am using Excel 2013. Unfortunately only one of the 3 rows i need to delete is blank. The others have content.